# Why roll back transactions in a Spring test environment?

Tags: spring

from [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx):

> One common issue in tests that access a real database is their effect
> on the state of the persistence store. Even when you use a development
> database, changes to the state may affect future tests. Also, many
> operations — such as inserting or modifying persistent data — cannot
> be performed (or verified) outside of a transaction.
>
> The TestContext framework addresses this issue. By default, the
> framework creates and rolls back a transaction for each test. You can
> write code that can assume the existence of a transaction. If you call
> transactionally proxied objects in your tests, they behave correctly,
> according to their configured transactional semantics. In addition, if
> a test method deletes the contents of selected tables while running
> within the transaction managed for the test, the transaction rolls
> back by default, and the database returns to its state prior to
> execution of the test. Transactional support is provided to a test by
> using a PlatformTransactionManager bean defined in the test’s
> application context.
>
> If you want a transaction to commit (unusual, but occasionally useful
> when you want a particular test to populate or modify the database),
> you can tell the TestContext framework to cause the transaction to
> commit instead of roll back by using the @Commit annotation.

How can we be certain that a transactional test was successful if the transaction is rolled back after it? Perhaps the test will be failed as a result of the transaction failing upon commit, for instance because of a violation of a SQL constraint (in relational databases transactions). or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, by default transaction got roll-back so that state of database remains unchanged.

For cases like unique constraint violation, ideally you should be verifying exception  message/code which your application is throwing other than verifying state of transaction in unit tests.

Please note, you don't require to verify if rollback actually rolling back transaction or not, but you need to verify if error is thrown from your application  after constraint violation occurred.
So your success criteria in this case is to check error is thrown after trying to insert duplicate record, and to check if error message which you have thrown from your method is correct.

For cases like `update`/`insert` to table, you can mark test case with explicit commit & verify it by executing select query within test; that will be your success criteria.

Comment: consider a situation in which I expect(based on the argument of the method) my service method to throw an exception when the transaction is going to commit (I want later handle it in a ControllerAdvice for example, and send an appropriate message to the user). if the transaction is never going to commit then no exception is thrown, so how to test this kind of functionality?

Comment: @mhrsalehi :      In your unit test, when you call your real  method & if it throws exception as a part of committing a transaction, you will get exception thrown from your real method.  Remember, in tests , transaction will get rolled back after end of test,  so whatever you do within test will still work. For example,  if in test you are committing record ,  record will get  committed , you can assert that after commit within test & once unit test completes, your committed record get rolled back. Hope I am able to explain you properly :-)